# How to input data in ALL present text fields in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to type the same sentence in all the present text fields.

For example, I'm trying to type "dsafafsa". The identifier always changes.

Here is the code:

textarea id="3765_id_50" name="entry_field[2679]" style="width:350px;" rows="3" wrap="physical">

textarea id="3772_id_100" name="entry_field[2686]" style="width:350px;" rows="3" wrap="physical">

I deleted < in front of the text area because it wasn't showing the code.

So far I only have,

```
type  xpath=(//textarea[contains(@name, 'entry')])   sdafdsfsdafsda
```

but it only types it in the first text box it sees.

Answer (score 1):

So given today's question and yesterday's it shows you're really hitting the limits of the IDE right now. Especially given that you seem to have an advanced knowledge of locators I would really suggest migrating to WebDriver

Here is the answer:
Say you have 2 elements like you mentioned; then your code is

```
type xpath=(//textarea[contains(@name, 'entry')])[1]  sdafdsfsdafsda
type xpath=(//textarea[contains(@name, 'entry')])[2]  sdafdsfsdafsda
```

the [1] corresponds with the first element selenium finds and the [2] the second.

There are problems with this in the IDE of course, because you have to manually enter this command for every box you have, so if you had 10 boxes then that is 10 manual insertions and then the maintenance to fix something if it fails. WebDriver has much better api's to deal with these kind of situations that you can't access with the IDE. I would suggest that if you're serious about selenium that you look into it.

*EDIT*

By the way migrating out of the IDE isn't that bad. So the IDE has some fun functions where you can actually save tests in some kind of programming language. So you can do that, and with a little bit extra work you can start running all those tests you worked so hard on without the IDE.

Comment: I'm actually a beginner with IDE. I just started using it about two weeks ago. I'm in an internship that requires me to do automated testing with Selenium IDE.

Do you know any good websites that has a introduction of WebDriver?

I'm actually trying to type it in ALL the text fields because the website I'm testing is able to add extra text fields.

Comment: @Raymond as I mentioned there is no native function for the IDE that can do this, you have to give explicit instructions to the IDE. If there are more boxes than you specified well tough luck, or go back and fix the test. WebDriver has api's that will allow you to do this, it involves some coding, but you have the ability to choose a language you're comfortable with. Try the [Selenium Documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html)

Comment: How would I do this using WebDriver or PHPUnit?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should add "Selenium IDE: Flow Control" to your browser and then enter the following lines:

```
store 1 FIELD_NUMBER

storeElementPresent xpath=(//textarea[contains(@name, 'entry')])[${FIELD_NUMBER}] FIELD_EXISTS

while ${FIELD_EXISTS}==true

type xpath=(//textarea[contains(@name, 'entry')])[${FIELD_NUMBER}] sdafdsfsdafsda

storeEval storedVars['FIELD_NUMBER']=${FIELD_NUMBER}+1

storeElementPresent xpath=(//textarea[contains(@name, 'entry')])[${FIELD_NUMBER}] 
FIELD_EXISTS

endWhile
```